# Input button onclick event handler does not reconize the select dropdown name (itemName)

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, html-select

I have this select dropdown menu with a name itemName. I also mad an input button with the onclick eventhandler containing the name of the select dorpdown. The problem is that the input button onclick does not reconize the select name (itemName).

```
<select name="itemName">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
document.write("<option>" + products[i].item + "</option>");
}
</script>
</select>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Get Info" onclick="var i = 
document.prodForm.itemName.selectedIndex;products[i].displayOne();" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off getting the select by a unique ID, e.g.:

```
<select id="itemName">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      document.write("<option>" + products[i].item + "</option>");
    }
    -->
  </script>
</select>
<form>
  <input type="button" value="Get Info" onclick="var i = document.getElementById('itemName').selectedIndex;products[i].displayOne();" />
</form>
```